# Why does the diagram show 2 link between LAN switches

Tags: networking, ethernet, lan, cisco

The diagram below shows a typical enterprise LAN using ethernet and wireless LAN access points.

Each LAN switch on each floor connects to a centralized distribution switch.

The question is why are there 2 links between each switch and the SWD.[image: Diagram]

Comment: Off Topic For here, Try http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com .  But my guess is LACP / Ether channel to increase BW between SW? and SWD. (IE you have 48 G Ports, and 2 x 10G uplinks).

Comment: Thanks I did not know this website exists

Comment: It could be channel aggregation, but it could also simply be redundant links. STP will block one link while the other is up in order to prevent STP loops. Link aggregation fools STP into believing it is a single link to prevent this blocking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would imagine it is either being used to increase throughput and/or redundancy. Have a look at [Link Aggregation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_aggregation)

Answer (score 0):

It's Ether Channel Technology. Because of that technology switches can send data on two ways and of course the biggest advantage is load balancing. If there are so traffic on ways, EC isusefull. When one of channel is down, other one keep sending (security)